# RewriteRule using Negative Lookahead results in Server Error

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule which uses Negative Lookahead

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(?!.*(contact|about|subscribe)).*$ /$1/?section=other
```

The url result expected is domain.com/dir/?section=other when the request is other than dir/contact etc.
When the file is placed on the server, the result is **Internal Server Error**.

[Here it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/podIto/1)

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I'm as clueless as a school bus on Sunday on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the file is placed on the server, the result is Internal Server Error

You are getting 500 (Internal Server Error) because your rule is running into loop as regex pattern keeps matching rewritten URL also which is `/dir/`.

You may use this rule to fix this:

```sh
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(?!.*(contact|about|subscribe|favorite)).+$ $1/?section=other [QSA,L,NC]
```

Note use of `.+` after `/` to prevent it to match just `/dir/`.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/podIto/2)

Comment: That solved the problem. Nicely done! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess Rules file. You could check its uri part to make sure not required parts are not present in it, then we could perform rewriting on uris. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also make sure your htaccess file is present in root folder of yours.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(contact|about|subscribe) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1/?section=other [QSA,L]
```